# If Ascii operators are definable, why not Unicode Symbols?

Tags: unicode, f#, operators, symbols, localization

I'm sure I join many in being glad there's finally a powerful language tied tightly to a mainstream GUI/Database/Communication framework.

I haven't been sure where to post this, but here seems the best spot.

I need to use Unicode symbol characters either as operators or as function names. I'd like syntactic sugar, but I don't need it.

Guy Steele pointed out in Communications of the ACM that "*" was a forced choice when it was adopted from Ascii as multiply, but my software works in Unicode, so I'm not tethered to Ascii anymore.

!$%&*+-./<=>?,@^|~:

Part of localization includes local programmers. Why limit the set of operators that can be defined in F#? It isn’t orthogonal to C#'s and F#'s acceptance of many Unicode IsLetter in identifiers.

Also, F# is likely to be used for symbolic manipulation of problems from logic, math, physicists, etc. It makes work much easier if there’s a direct mapping into the language of the basic operators. (F# and C# accept many Unicode IsLetter? as well as IsDigit’?   This is a request to allow Unicode IsSymbol? As operators with the precedence of, for example, *, or, since “+” is both a unary and binary operator, I could put up with the precedence of + and make up the difference with parenthesized groupings.

Consider the domain-specific needs of logicians, mathematicians, physicists, etc. I’d rather write a symbolic differentiator or integrator using math symbols than Ascii permutations of already-taken operators.

- Logic: ∀ ∃ ⇒
- Math: ∑ ∫ ∂
- Group theory: ≤ ≥ ∈ ∉
- Set Theory: ⊆ ⊇ ⊃ ∪ ∩
- Tensors: ⊗

I’ve written many languages in other languages, but because F# is tightly .Net-integrated, this issue poses special challenges without language support:

It’s trivial to cobble up a translator that takes Unicode-operator F# source and maps it, line-by-line, to Ascii-operator F# source.

But when debugging, how do I make sure the programmer still sees their untranslated source?  And that they can see variable values.

Operators and converts them is trivial. But how do I ensure the translation is what gets compiled, while the programmer sees their own source?  If I map line-for-line correctly, how do I ensure they can still point at a variable and see its value?

Comment: I've added the f# tag, but to do so I had to get rid of the math tag. I think that's a fair trade (the core problem here is something f# people might now about, rather than something for mathematicians to ponder)

Comment: See also http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/9690.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is a math (Unicode) symbol extension for F# available in the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fe627c2a-5d09-4252-bcc7-300821ae707c).

This allows you to define Unicode symbols, e.g.:

```
let inline (~∑) xs = xs |> Seq.sum

let total = ∑myList
```

Answer (score 1):

Other languages, such as Scala, do permit operators from outside the ASCII range -- mathematical symbols(Sm) and other symbols(So)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Project Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community) which is a new functional programming language that embraces the Unicode character set (among many other features). In particular, see the [Mathematical Syntax in Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/wiki/MathSyntaxInFortress) page which contains some sample code.

Comment: My interest is strong in F# because .Net can be used to create any application that doesn't need C++ performance. And Project Fortress sounds interesting. Thanks.

Comment: It appears this project has been discontinued. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language)

Answer (score 1):

For an interesting discussion on this check: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/9690.aspx

Comment: This answer duplicates Brian's comment above.